# Saving data from MVC view without navigating to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to save data from MVC view to the database without navigating to the controller? Is this possible? If so how can I achieve it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Saving data in database from the view violates the basic principles of MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

While technically possible, all backend access should happen in the controller, if you want to stay true to the MVC design pattern.

Note that you can submit data to a controller action using AJAX, so the page from which you send the data will not be reloaded. For example, use [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).